# Laravel Error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DateTime' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5.6

```
public function recover(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    // Create tokens
    $selector = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
    $token = random_bytes(32);

    $url = sprintf('%s',  route('recover.reset',['selector'=>$selector, 'validator'=>bin2hex($token)]));

    // Token expiration
    $expires = new DateTime('NOW');
    $expires->add(new DateInterval('PT01H')); // 1 hour

    // Delete any existing tokens for this user
    DB::delete('delete * from password_reset where email =?', $email);

    // Insert reset token into database
    $insert = $this->db->insert('password_reset', 
        array(
            'email'     =>  $email,
            'selector'  =>  $selector, 
            'token'     =>  hash('sha256', $token),
            'expires'   =>  $expires->format('U'),
        )
    );
```

Am trying to implement forgot password
when the email form is submitted to forgotPasswordController
it generates the below error

> "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DateTime' not found"

This is the picture of the controller the above code is not there is i cant modify it
[RecoverPasswordController Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nLS.png)

At the header i have tried using

```
use DateTime;
```

Or

```
use App\Http\Controllers\DateTime
```

But still generates same error
please help fixing it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Use `new \DateTime()` or Laravel's `Carbon` class

Comment: When you used `use DateTime;` in the header, the error was still **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DateTime' not found**?

Comment: Yes it was still not found?

Comment: I cant modify the above code

Comment: I was able to fix it using namespace
`use DateTime;`
But I had 2 duplicate ForgotPasswordController in different directories
so i had to locate the controller it was pointing to.

Thank Y'all.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Above your class definition, import the class with a use statement.

```
use DateTime;
```

The alternative to that is to use the fully qualified namespace in your code. With PHP classes in the global namespace, all this means is a single backslash before the class name:

```
$expires = new \DateTime('NOW');
```

I prefer the first approach, as it allows you to see every class used in that file at a glance.

Comment: `$currentTime = new \DateTime('now');` defining an like this directly working fine

Answer (score 4):

DateTime is a PHP Object, so you can declare it using the slash before:

```
new \DateTime();
```

Or declaring it before you use and instantiating later:

```
use DateTime;

class Etc
{
    public function test()
    {
        $datetime = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a backslash `\` (to define `root namespace`)

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
```

also you can use classes

```
use DateTime;
use DatePeriod;
use DateInterval;
```

Answer (score -1):

By Using below Classes works for me.

```
use DateTime;
use DatePeriod;
use DateIntercal;
```